# TinyMCE plugin not showing euro symbol

Tags: tinymce, euro

I use the last update of the TinyMce plugin and **I have a problem with the € key**. Nothing happens when I want to insert this € symbol [with ctrl + alt + e].

I read the doc but I dont know what to edit for make it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TinyMce you can "insert special character" with a plugin

It is in the TinyMce documentation :
"This plugin adds a charmap toolbar button that enables users to insert special characters into their text. It also adds the menu item Special character under the Insert menu."

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/charmap/

Hope this helps